# Comparing date by combining it

Tags: date, comparison

Im just wondering. is it ok to combine years,month, and day of two date and make a comparison based on the combination.

eg:
    `Date A: 12th-January-2019`
    `Date B: 24th-December-2018`

Based on the above date, i could combine the year,month, and day as follow:

    `Date A: 20190112`
    `Date B: 20181224`

So based on the numbers, i could do logic like below to compare which date comes first:

```
if(Date A > Date B) {
    output("Date A is the latest")
}
```

i would like to implement this method just to compare which is the latest date.
are there any problem of doing so.

Comment: Which programming language are you using? As long as your year is 4 digits (so in the range from year 0001 through year 9999), it will work, but many languages come with a date-time library that is better suited for the job.

Comment: @OleV.V.im using java. the reason im doing this is because i need to migrate a live production data. before this, users been entering different kind of delimeter to seperate the date. eg: 2018/12/19, 2017-02-01, 2018.03.04, 2019\09\12, 2014:03:01(yes, this actually exist in the database).

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

Since you are using Java, I suggest that you take advantage of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    String[] dateStringsFromDatabase = {
                "2018/12/19",
                "2017-02-01",
                "2018.03.04",
                "25-12-2016", // reversed
                "2019\\09\\12",
                "2014:03:01"
            };

    List<LocalDate> parsedDates = new ArrayList<>(dateStringsFromDatabase.length);
    for (String dateString : dateStringsFromDatabase) {
        // No matter which delimiter is used, replace it with a hyphen
        String text = dateString.replaceAll("\\W", "-");
        try {
            parsedDates.add(LocalDate.parse(text));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println(dateString + " not parsed: " + dtpe.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 25-12-2016 not parsed: Text '25-12-2016' could not be parsed at index 0
> ```

What this approach buys you is validation of the dates even though they come with all different delimiters. Especially in this situation I believe that you should want to validate that your strings are within the expected variations. Otherwise you risk that a date with the numbers reversed ends up as a date in year 2512, for example. You want to catch that before it happens.

Example of comparing which comes first:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < parsedDates.size(); i++) {
        LocalDate dateA = parsedDates.get(i - 1);
        LocalDate dateB = parsedDates.get(i);
        if (dateA.isAfter(dateB)) {
            System.out.format("%s is later than %s%n", dateA, dateB);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2018-12-19 is later than 2017-02-01
> 2019-09-12 is later than 2014-03-01
> ```

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.